# Forwarding template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to forward a template parameter to a parent class (from a subclass), however I am getting the following error when trying to do so;

```cpp
test.cc:9:46: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class A, class B> class BaseClass’
 class SubClass : public BaseClass<SubClass, B> {
                                              ^
test.cc:9:46: error:   expected a type, got ‘SubClass’
```

Here is the code I am trying to run;

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename A, typename B>
class BaseClass {

};

template<typename B>
class SubClass : public BaseClass<SubClass, B> { // Trying to forward B to the second parameter

};

int main(void) {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have tried prefixing `B` with `typename`, but I get the following error instead;

```cpp
test.cc:9:55: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class A, class B> class BaseClass’
 class SubClass : public BaseClass<SubClass, typename B> {
                                                       ^
test.cc:9:55: error:   expected a type, got ‘SubClass’
test.cc:9:55: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Comment: `class SubClass : public BaseClass<SubClass<B>, B> {};`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That's it! Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki,  I agree. However, OP may be trying to pass the class itself, in which case `BaseClass` would need to be `template<template<class...> class A, typename... B> class BaseClass{};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<typename B>
class SubClass : public BaseClass<SubClass<B>, B>
//                                        ^^^
{

};
```

`SubClass` is an *injected name* that can be used to refer to `SubClass<B>` only in the scope of `SubClass`. Outside, it is the name of a *class template* itself (that it, it requires a template parameter list `<>` to form a type).

§ 9 [class]/p2:

> The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.

§ 3.3.2 [basic.scope.pdecl]/p8:

> The point of declaration for an *injected-class-name* (Clause 9) is immediately following the opening brace of
>   the class definition.

§ 14.6.1 [temp.local]/p1:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an *injected-class-name* (Clause 9). The *injected-class-name* can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*. When it is used with a template-argument-list,
>   as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent
>   to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`.

Comment: It turns out my actual code (not this test code) has a much deeper issue, but this resolves the issue I posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use the injected-class-name. However,

> The *class-name* is also inserted into the **scope of the class** itself;
>   this is known as the *injected-class-name*.

The base-clause is not looking up names that are within the scope of the class. Hence  you have to supply the argument list yourself.

```
template<typename B>
class SubClass : public BaseClass<SubClass<B>, B> { /*..*/ };
```